# reference a div using querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to reference a button in the event click, to access the `a` tags on the `dropdown Content` div and set the display as `block`. How can I do this?

```js
const dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownBtn')
for (const button of dropdownBtn) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const links = document.querySelectorAll(`.${button} + .dropdownContent a`)
    links.forEach(link => link.style.display = 'block')
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button1</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button2</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at this code, I think you meant to select the next sibling

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(`.${button} + .dropdownContent a`)
```

Instead of using the `+`, you can use

```
const links = button.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll(".dropdownContent a")
```

For example, without creating an extra `links` variable:

```js
const dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownBtn')
for (const button of dropdownBtn) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    button.nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll(".dropdownContent a")
      .forEach(link => link.style.display = 'block')
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button1</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button2</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will set the `a` elements to `block` only for the `.dropdownContent` that is the next sibling of the button.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownBtn').forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    const dropdownDiv = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdownDiv.children.length; i++) {
      dropdownDiv.children[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownBtn').forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', (evt) => {
    const dropdownDiv = evt.target.nextElementSibling;
    for (let i = 0; i < dropdownDiv.children.length; i++) {
      dropdownDiv.children[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button1</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button2</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div>
  <ul id="test">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, this can be accomplished by getting the parent Element of the current Button and then only querying its children.

I did it like this:

```js
const dropdownBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdownBtn')
for (const button of dropdownBtn) {
  button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const links = button.parentElement.querySelectorAll(`.dropdownContent a`)
    links.forEach(link => link.style.display = 'block')
  })
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button1</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button2</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over the outer dropdown containers then you can query the elements inside that container.

Example toggling a class rather than inline style:

```js
const dropdown = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
dropdown.forEach(el => {
  el.querySelector('.dropdownBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    el.querySelectorAll('.dropdownContent a').forEach(link => link.classList.toggle('active'))
  });
});
```

```css
a.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button1</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class=dropdown>
    <button class='dropdownBtn'>Button2</button>
    <div class="dropdownContent">
      <a href="#">Test1</a>
      <a href="#">Test2</a>
      <a href="#">Test3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't vote your commente, but thanks for the help, will help me